# Why do I get error JwtStrategy requires a secret or key?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I get this error "TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key" and I can't figure out how to fix it. What can I do to fix it?

```
(node:46218) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [Bus]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
/mnt/data/Workspace/Development/comichaven/api/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:45
        throw new TypeError('JwtStrategy requires a secret or key');
        ^

TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key
    at new JwtStrategy (/mnt/data/Workspace/Development/comichaven/api/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:45:15)
    at module.exports (/mnt/data/Workspace/Development/comichaven/api/config/passport.js:14:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/data/Workspace/Development/comichaven/api/server.js:40:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What I have tried

- renaming the varable opts
- checked so the variables are named the same
- tried using dotenv
- replacing keys.secretOrKey with a string

passport.js

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model("users");
const keys = require("./keys")

const opts = {};

opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretKey = keys.secretOrKey;

module.exports = passport => {
    passport.use(
        new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
            User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
            .then(user => {
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, user)
                }
                return done(null, false)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
        })
    )
}
```

keys.js

```
module.exports = {
    secretOrKey: 'secret'
};
```

Comment: Can you confirm the keys.secretOrKey; above is actually holding the value expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use right key name for secretkey in options. You should write like this:-

```
opts.secretOrKey = keys.secretOrKey
```

By mistake you wrote opts.secretKey.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

My mistake is  this I import( `import { Strategy } from "passport-jwt";`) instead of
`import { Strategy } from "passport-local"`;

Answer (score 0):

1.change the import to

```
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
```

2.if then got import error then install use this cammnd :

> npm install @nestjs/passport passport passport-local

Answer (score -2):

1. You can also install mongoDB:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

2. Inside `keys` file:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
     jwt: process.env.JWT
   }
   ```
3. When the server is installed and configured use terminal/command line
   to attach the key value. In my case it was:

   ```
   export NODE_ENV=production
   export JWT=jwt-prod
   export MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost/db
   ```